# Is ngcc still required to run when using ivy compatible libraries

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, ivy

I often read that ngcc is required to compile non-ivy compatible libraries to ivy compatible ones.
So I set up a new angular project (version 11) with the latest material library (version 11).

Since the material library is from the angular team, I suppose the library is already ivy compatible. To confirm my assumption i checked the package.json and it gave me entry points for the following modules:

```
  "main": "./bundles/material.umd.js",
  "fesm2015": "./fesm2015/material.js",
  "esm2015": "./esm2015/index.js",
  "typings": "./index.d.ts",
  "module": "./fesm2015/material.js",
  "es2015": "./fesm2015/material.js"
```

So to me it seems like angular material is already compiled into all those module formats.

But after running npm start / run build ngcc still compiles "es2015" to "esm2015" modules.

```
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
...
```

This leads me to the following questions:

- Have i mixed up the concepts/topics "module formats" and "ivy compatibility"? (eg. does angular/material provide all those module formats, but not in an ivy compatible way?)
- Why is it compiling es2015 as esm2015, when angular material already contains esm2015 modules?
- And why is the angular cli compiling them to esm2015 when they are already present in the first place?
- It's often encouraged to add a postinstall hook that runs ngcc. But why would i need it, when all libraries are already compliant?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that Angular currently discourages to publish ivy libraries. [Source](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#publishing-your-library).

So I suppose that @angular/material isn't yet compiled as an ivy library.

Regarding the compilation to ESM2015 - this might have something to do with the [Angular Library format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview). [ESM2015 is basically ES2015 code with additional import/export statements](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/bundle-angular-esm2015-with-rollup).

So yes, running ngcc is still required, since there is no ivy compliant library out there yet. But once that's the case we shouldn't need it anymore.